# New web to print solution

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, customization

I'm working on a web-shop with a personalize function. The web-shop is going to sell prints. Before customers goes to check out, they will be able to customize their product/print with just changing custom text on the designs. I know their is many different web2print solutions. I'm thinking about using Adobe's Scene7 web to print solution. It's a service and will cost money, so I rather do something more simple.

The thing is that most web2print solutions are so advanced with so  many edit options. I just want to have limited rows of text to customize.

So my idea was to make the designs in html and css. With a basic background image and text on top of the background image. When the customer is done filling in the form for the text and clicks order. The web pages makes the html-css coded customised design and makes it to an image that gets mounted on high resolution printable pdf.

There is many web to pdf solutions, but the problem is that they doesn't seem to make an exact flat copy of what's shown in the design. I want this to work server side.

In my head this doesn't seem so advanced, maby i'm missing something?

I know css and html good, I can also handle javascript and some php. But i'm also open to learn new languages and programming skills to get this to work.

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 1):

Use SVG which is the standard vector format (can be resized without loss in quality) and will look the same across implementations.

Comment: Thank you so much, you made my day! :) It really helped me look in the right direction. Now I know how i will do it, even if i don't know all the details yet. I will update this post with some relevant code and probably ask for more help later during the progress.